# MySQL: Update Trigger with where clause

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables, lists and users.

I’m trying to create a trigger that updates the users table with a value from the lists table, where column values match, but it's not working.

I could use IF statements, but there are two many combinations in the real data, so I was hoping to use a where clause. Example: where user1 = value1 and user2 = value2 and user3 = value 3. In the real data there is always a match.

Here is an image to explain the two tables with the desired outcome in the user_output column. Dog is correct, because user1 matches value1, user2 matches value2 and user3 matches value3.

[image]

Here is the trigger I have been trying:

```
CREATE  TRIGGER trigger_1
            BEFORE UPDATE
            ON users
            FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
         IF (NEW.user1 <> OLD.user1 or new.user2 <> old.user2 or new.user <> old.user3 ) THEN
    SET NEW.user_output = ( SELECT value4
      FROM lists
    where users.user1 = lists.value1 and users.user2 = lists.value2 and users.user3 = lists.value3
LIMIT 1 );
end if;
END;
```

DB Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d63fe3af02bd55fd2fe51cba1ba3c05d

Comment: What is unclear in the message "Unknown column '**user**' in 'NEW'" in your fiddle?

Comment: @Akina That’s an error I receive as a result of the trigger. If I move the update statement to above the trigger it executes correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_1
BEFORE UPDATE
ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.user1 <> OLD.user1 or new.user2 <> old.user2 or new.user3 <> old.user3 ) THEN
    SET NEW.user_output = ( SELECT value4
                            FROM lists
                            where NEW.user1 = lists.value1 
                              and NEW.user2 = lists.value2
                              and NEW.user3 = lists.value3
                            LIMIT 1 );
end if;
END;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75629e35021ef5a62873cff46df1fa7b